# How to configure JavaC.sublime-builld for java packages

Tags: java, sublimetext2, sublimetext

How to configure JavaC.sublime-build to work with classes inside packages? This configuration only work for classes inside default package:

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file", "&&", "java", "$file_base_name"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "{filename}",
    "shell": true
}
```

How to pass the correct argument for the java command ("java", "$file_base_name")?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is currently no possible to implement the build from Java projects entirely in the JavaC.sublime-build. It's necessary to use build tools to achieve this (Ant, Maven, Gladle, Sbt, ...).